# Why must Sass files in Jekyll start with "two lines of triple dashes"?

Tags: syntax, sass, jekyll

The Jekyll documentation says:

> create a file with the proper extension name (one of `.sass`, `.scss`, or `.coffee`) and start the file with two lines of triple dashes, like this:
>
> ```
> ---
> ---
>
> // start content
> .my-definition
>   font-size: 1.2em
> ```

<sup>[Jekyll asset documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/)</sup>

But... **why?** I don't see any explanation anywhere of why Jekyll requires this. I'm worried that this will make it improper Sass/SCSS and I won't so easily be able to migrate my stuff out of Jekyll if I need to.

---

Additionally, I see many examples of people using Sass on GitHub's Jekyll without this practice.

For instance:

- [NSHipster.com](https://github.com/NSHipster/nshipster.com) (example from [screen.sass](https://github.com/NSHipster/nshipster.com/blob/master/assets/sass/screen.sass))

  ```
  @import './bourbon/bourbon'
  @import './neat/neat'
  @import './base/base'
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig a little further in the documentation you can find [why front matter ?](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/)

And it's only necessary for your entry scss/sass file.